# Thermal throttling on purpose on M1 MacBook Air

Tags: performance, games

I have been trying to game on the Macbook Air and for the games that I play I'm quite satisfied with the performance. Although, I noticed that even for non-demanding games, the CPU can run hot up to around 90 degrees. This might be a silly question, but is it possible to throttle the CPU on purpose? I don't mind a little bit of lag in my games if it means that I can stay comfortably at around 60-70 degrees. I'm mainly concerned about the longevity of the chip and the battery.

Comment: The design tolerance is 100°, similar to most modern processors. The Mac is doing its job just right.

Comment: In System Preferences activating Battery > Low power mode (in the Battery or Power Adapter Tab) should have a throttling effect.

Comment: Apple has designed this new chip and the MBA that goes around it with heat production and dissipation in mind. You're not going to manage it better than Apple's Engineers. The heat produced is well within tolerances and is not going to affect the lifespan of the machine.